# Dynamic link to last document in a library

Tags: document-library, document, promoted-links

Only started using Sharepoint2013 recently. Office poweruser with some VBA-knowledge.

We would like to launch an office document from a promoted link. More specificaly it should be the last uploaded document on a view of a library.

In our setup we're requested to restrict on any customising of sharepoint...

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Content Query Web Part.
In this WebPart you can set up the Document library you want to query by, filtering, ordering and many more things. When you edit a page just click on add WebPart and select Content Rollup group. You will find Content Query WebPart.
Then, configure as many options as you want.

You can find here some guidelines http://phyllisinit.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/sharepoint-2010-content-query-show-files-which-are-modified-recently/

If you only need the last modified document Limit the number of items to display to 1 and order by Created or Modified field

Comment: Thanks Alvmad, until that part I'm still OK. From that result I want to have the promoted link open the result of that query in a new window... Making sure that my content uploader don't need to mess around setting links to a document that will be outdated several times a month.

Comment: Check out this link http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2012/07/24/how-to-open-content-query-web-part-links-in-a-new-ie-window.aspx  Tell me if that is what you need

Comment: Hello Alvmad, ll is pointing in the right direction but does not yet allow that clicking the promoted link launches the document found by the query web part in a new window.

Comment: Hello Alvmad, I rechecked the linkk you send me. Sorry but it is not what I'm looking for. Now I have a promoted link opening th edocument in a new window. Whenever somebody is uploading a new document, they need to change the link manualy. I realy need a way to link the promoted link tile dynamicaly to the "last uploaded doculment in the library". don't know if this makes sence?

Comment: I cannot understad what you are looking for. With Content Query By WebPart you can recreate the behaviour you need (or at least what I understood).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Alvmad. I think I may be asking something that needs customising... I think I will change my intention to launch the file by clicking the promoted link. I'll indeed show the result of the content query by webpart and show that in the page. The user will then have to click the file to launch it. Thanks again for your time.